# Check python program for errors

Tags: python, testing, syntax-error, static-code-analysis

How can I check a python program for errors without running it? I want to get the error messages that say what line my error is on, but I do not want to execute the program.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use code analysis tools like [`pylint`](http://www.pylint.org/).

`pylint` is the most popular, but there are others:

- [`flake8`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/flake8)
- [`pyflakes`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyflakes)
- [code inspection](http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/webhelp/code-inspection.html) tools in [Pycharm IDE](http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/)
- [`Codeq`](https://codeq.io/) service (if you are on github)

Hope that helps.